# How to return all selenium elements that matches a whole words

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am running selenium on python to return all elements that matches keywords.

```
url =...
svc = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path="driver_path")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=svc)
driver.get(url)

key_words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
# This will match if the text is equal to one of the keywords
predicate_text = " or ".join([f"translate(normalize-space(text()), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='{text}'" for text in key_words])
# The problem is here as it does not match only whole words.
predicate_href = " or ".join([f"contains(translate(@href, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'{text}') " for text in key_words])

href1 = /xxx/yyyy/word1/ good match
href2 = /xxword1yy/ bad match.
```

How Can I do exact match ?

Answer (score 0):

Constructing such xPath is some kind of olympiad challenge and not a good practice.
It's better to get elements with href attributes and parse them via language tools like regexp, etc.
Resulted xPath for you condition is hard to read and hard to maintain.
However, if you are trying to solve challenge by using xPath expression, you can make union 2 or condition.

First part checks if the lowercased `href` attribute contains the `/{text}/`. It uses `translate` to convert the `href` to lowercase and `concat` to ensure that the text is surrounded by slashes.

Second part covers condition when word doesn't have `/` on the end of the url. `string-length` gets the length of the `href`, and `substring` extracts the portion of the href starting from the calculated position to the end.

```py
key_words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
predicate_href_exact = " or ".join([f"""
(contains(concat('/', translate(@href, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '/'), '/{text}/') or
substring(translate(@href, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), string-length(translate(@href, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')) - string-length('{text}') + 1) = '/{text}')
""" for text in key_words])
pattern = f"//*[{predicate_href_exact}]"
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, pattern)

for element in elements:
    print(element.get_attribute('href'))
```